# Why is the "new" keyword so much more efficient than assignment?

Tags: java, performance, new-operator

I've got two methods to read in a string, and create Character objects:

```
static void newChar(String string) {
    int len = string.length();
    System.out.println("Reading " + len + " characters");
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        Character cur = new Character(string.charAt(i));

    }       
}
```

and

```
static void justChar(String string) {
    int len = string.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        Character cur = string.charAt(i);

    }
}
```

When I run the methods using an 18,554,760 character string, I'm getting wildly different run times. The output I'm getting is:

```
newChar took: 20 ms
justChar took: 41 ms
```

With smaller input (4,638,690 characters) the time isn't as varied.

```
newChar took: 12 ms
justChar took: 13 ms
```

Why is new so much more efficient in this case?

EDIT:

My benchmark code is pretty hacky.

```
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
newChar(largeString);
end = System.currentTimeMillis();
diff = end-start;
System.out.println("New char took: " + diff + " ms");

start = System.currentTimeMillis();
justChar(largeString);
end = System.currentTimeMillis();
diff = end-start;
System.out.println("just char took: " + diff+ " ms");
```

Comment: Please show us your benchmark code.

Comment: This is microbenchmark? Can you repeat this benchmark with similar result?

Comment: How do the results compare if you call the methods in a loop a million times?  (And take out the `System.out.println` so as to not skew the results, of course.)

Comment: I updated the post with the benchmark code.

Comment: Reverse the order of your tests in the benchmark and see if you get the same behavior.

Comment: You're gonna need to loop much more than that. Otherwise, you're just gonna be hitting warm-up effects of the JVM. Have you tried switching the order of the tests?

Comment: ...by the way, I'd (strongly) suggest using a proper microbenchmark framework that accounts for warmup &c. Criterium is the gold standard for Clojure; for pure Java, try https://code.google.com/p/caliper/

Comment: Read about Microbenchmarks first.

Comment: When switched I'm still getting the same results. I had no idea about JVM warmup or microbenchmarks, thanks for all the answers.

Comment: ...also, the Caliper project's introductory page on microbenchmarking Java is a sane place to start: https://code.google.com/p/caliper/wiki/JavaMicrobenchmarks

Comment: I have confirmed OP's results in `jmh`: for my string, `justChar` takes 38 µsec and `newChar` takes 19 µsec.

Comment: Could you report back when you've tested with actual benchmarks? Using a string of 15 million characters I get `10` vs `16` but 150 million immediately jumps to `70` vs `160` and 500 million is `230` vs `520`. [Testing code](https://ideone.com/MJnH4a) for those who want. Don't forget to increase the heap size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### TL;DR section

#### Good news

Your measurement does expose a real effect.

#### Bad news

It does so mostly by chance because your benchmark has many technical flaws, and the effect it exposes is probably not the one you have in mind.

The `new Character()` approach is faster *if and only if* HotSpot's Escape Analysis succeeds in proving that the resulting instance can be safely allocated on the stack instead of heap. Therefore the effect is not nearly as general as implied in your question.

#### Explanation of effect

The reason why `new Character()` is faster is *locality of reference*: your instance is on the stack and all access to it is via CPU cache hits. When you reuse a cached instance, you must

1. access a remote `static` field;
2. dereference it into a remote array;
3. dereference an array entry into a remote `Character` instance;
4. acces the `char` contained in that instance.

Each dereference is a potential CPU cache miss. Furthermore, it forces a part of the cache to be redirected towards those remote locations, causing more cache misses on the input string and/or the stack locations.

### DETAILS

I have run this code with `jmh`:

```
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
public class Chars {
  static String string = "12345678901234567890"; static {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) string += string;
  }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  public void newChar() {
    int len = string.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) new Character(string.charAt(i));
  }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  public void justChar() {
    int len = string.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) Character.valueOf(string.charAt(i));
  }
}
```

This keeps the essence of your code, but eliminates some systematic errors like warmup and compilation times. These are the results:

```
Benchmark              Mode Thr    Cnt  Sec         Mean   Mean error    Units
o.s.Chars.justChar     avgt   1      3    5       39.062        6.587  usec/op
o.s.Chars.newChar      avgt   1      3    5       19.114        0.653  usec/op
```

And this would be my best guess at what's going on:

- in `newChar` you are creating a *fresh* instance of `Character`. HotSpot's Escape Analysis can prove the instance never escapes, therefore it allows stack allocation, or, in the special case of `Character`, could eliminate the allocation altogether because the data from it is provably never used;
- in `justChar` you involve lookup into the `Character` cache array, which has *some* cost.

### UPDATE

In response to Aleks's criticism, I added some more methods to the benchmark. The main effect remains stable, but we get even more fine-grained details about the lesser optimization effects.

```
  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  public int newCharUsed() {
    int len = string.length(), sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) sum += new Character(string.charAt(i));
    return sum;
  }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  public int justCharUsed() {
    int len = string.length(), sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) sum += Character.valueOf(string.charAt(i));
    return sum;
  }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  public void newChar() {
    int len = string.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) new Character(string.charAt(i));
  }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  public void justChar() {
    int len = string.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) Character.valueOf(string.charAt(i));
  }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  public void newCharValue() {
    int len = string.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) new Character(string.charAt(i)).charValue();
  }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  public void justCharValue() {
    int len = string.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) Character.valueOf(string.charAt(i)).charValue();
  }
```

#### DESCRIPTION:

- the base versions are `justChar` and `newChar`;
- `...Value` methods add the `charValue` call to the base version;
- `...Used` methods add both the `charValue` call (implicitly) and *use* the value to preclude any Dead Code Elimination.

#### RESULTS:

```
Benchmark                   Mode Thr    Cnt  Sec         Mean   Mean error    Units
o.s.Chars.justChar          avgt   1      3    1      246.847        5.969  usec/op
o.s.Chars.justCharUsed      avgt   1      3    1      370.031       26.057  usec/op
o.s.Chars.justCharValue     avgt   1      3    1      296.342       60.705  usec/op
o.s.Chars.newChar           avgt   1      3    1      123.302       10.596  usec/op
o.s.Chars.newCharUsed       avgt   1      3    1      172.721        9.055  usec/op
o.s.Chars.newCharValue      avgt   1      3    1      123.040        5.095  usec/op
```

- there is evidence of *some* Dead Code Elimination (DCE) both in `justChar` and `newChar` variants, but it is only partial;
- with `newChar` variant, adding `charValue` has no effect so apparently it was DCE'd;
- with `justChar`, `charValue` does have an effect, so seems not to have been eliminated;
- DCE has a minor overall effect, as witnessed by the stable difference between `newCharUsed` and `justCharUsed`.

Answer (score 22):

Well, I'm not sure if Marko was intentional in replicating the original mistake. TL;DR; new instance is not used, gets eliminated. Adjusting the benchmark reverses the result. Don't trust faulty benchmarks, learn from them.

Here's the JMH benchmark:

```
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@Warmup(iterations = 3, time = 1)
@Measurement(iterations = 3, time = 1)
@Fork(3)
@State(Scope.Thread)
public class Chars {

    // Source needs to be @State field to avoid constant optimizations
    // on sources. Results need to be sinked into the Blackhole to
    // avoid dead-code elimination
    private String string;

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
        string = "12345678901234567890";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            string += string;
        }
    }

    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public void newChar_DCE(BlackHole bh) {
        int len = string.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            Character c = new Character(string.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public void justChar_DCE(BlackHole bh) {
        int len = string.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            Character c = Character.valueOf(string.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public void newChar(BlackHole bh) {
        int len = string.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            Character c = new Character(string.charAt(i));
            bh.consume(c);
        }
    }

    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public void justChar(BlackHole bh) {
        int len = string.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            Character c = Character.valueOf(string.charAt(i));
            bh.consume(c);
        }
    }

    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public void newChar_prim(BlackHole bh) {
        int len = string.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            char c = new Character(string.charAt(i));
            bh.consume(c);
        }
    }

    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public void justChar_prim(BlackHole bh) {
        int len = string.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            char c = Character.valueOf(string.charAt(i));
            bh.consume(c);
        }
    }
}
```

...and this is the result:

```
Benchmark                   Mode   Samples         Mean   Mean error    Units
o.s.Chars.justChar          avgt         9       93.051        0.365    us/op
o.s.Chars.justChar_DCE      avgt         9       62.018        0.092    us/op
o.s.Chars.justChar_prim     avgt         9       82.897        0.440    us/op
o.s.Chars.newChar           avgt         9      117.962        4.679    us/op
o.s.Chars.newChar_DCE       avgt         9       25.861        0.102    us/op
o.s.Chars.newChar_prim      avgt         9       41.334        0.183    us/op
```

DCE stands for "Dead Code Elimination", and that is what the original benchmark is suffering from. If we eliminate that effect, in JMH's way it requires us to sink the values into the Blackhole, the score reverses. So, in retrospect, that seems to indicate the `new Character()` in the original code has major improvement with DCE, while the `Character.valueOf` is not that successful. I'm not sure we should discuss why, because this has no bearing on the real world use cases, where produced Characters are actually used.

You can go further on two fronts from here:

- Get the assembly for the benchmark methods to confirm the conjecture above. See [PrintAssembly](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PrintAssembly).
- Run with more threads. The difference between returning cached Character and instantiating the new one would diminish as we increase the number of threads, and consequently hit the "allocation wall".

**UPD:** Following up on Marko's question, it does seem the major impact is about eliminating the allocation itself, whether via the EA or DCE, see *_prim tests.

**UPD2:** Looked into the assembly. The same run with `-XX:-DoEscapeAnalysis` confirms the major effect is due to eliminating the allocation, as the effect of escape analysis:

```
Benchmark                   Mode   Samples         Mean   Mean error    Units
o.s.Chars.justChar          avgt         9       94.318        4.525    us/op
o.s.Chars.justChar_DCE      avgt         9       61.993        0.227    us/op
o.s.Chars.justChar_prim     avgt         9       82.824        0.634    us/op
o.s.Chars.newChar           avgt         9      118.862        1.096    us/op
o.s.Chars.newChar_DCE       avgt         9       97.530        2.485    us/op
o.s.Chars.newChar_prim      avgt         9      101.905        1.871    us/op
```

**This proves the original DCE conjecture is incorrect. EA is the major contributor.**
DCE results are still faster because we do not pay the costs of unboxing, and generally treating the returned value with any respect. Benchmark is faulty in that regard nevertheless.

Comment: You can't return the single Character instance, because many are produced in the loop. You need to sink every single one of them, otherwise you subject yourself for the loop specialization, and the removal of parts of the loop.

Comment: True, that slipped my attention... but if I really wanted to fix the benchmark, I would *do something* with the `Character` without letting it escape. I think that would be more fair because EA could be a part of the story and not a stray effect.

Comment: You are correct about the EA effects though. Should the ``Character`` be properly consumed by the immediately unboxing (see the updated post), the EA kicks in and contributes a lot of improvements. However, in the broken benchmark case, DCE shades off that effect completely! ;)

Comment: I still can't interpret your results as proving any DCE. The hypothesis that `justChar` involves a more expensive array lookup operation vs. copying of char value to a nearby stack location in the `newChar` case, still stands. Note that `*_prim` variants adds the same *constant time* in both cases, which is the `charValue` call.

Comment: Yeah, don't get me wrong: EA sure is the major contributor to the cause. However, whatever EA can do is further improved by DCE. If you look into the assembly for ```newChar_DCE```, you will find ```charAt()``` partially DCE-d.

Comment: (See the update; I have no idea why I haven't thought about this experiment in the first place)

Comment: I have updated my answer with more test cases. I think my results prove *some* DCE, but also show that it has a secondary effect to the overall timing.---Sorry, only now I see your additional comments. I guess we came to the same conclusion.

Comment: So, back to our OP's original benchmark, faulty as it may be---it does prove an important point: `Character` cache array lookup is more expensive than EA'd `new Character`.

Comment: I wouldn't say "erratic", but "complex"! This is the whole idea behind my benchmarking talks: the owls are not what they seem.

Comment: I've chanced upon an even stronger case for the "erratic" epithet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21708836/1103872. Deleting a line of code (a loop exit point) results in slower code. Reason: the line of code prevents a certain "optimization" which turns out to be *pessimization* on my CPU.