# Is a copy of an object made when pushing it through a method?

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, benchmarking, heap-memory

Suppose I have a `private static Integer i = 0` in my object's state. Suppose then that I push this through some method which takes this `i` as an argument as follows: `pushThroughMethod(i)`.

Does `i` get copied onto heap and become eligible for garbage collection?

Comment: `i` is static, so it won't be gc'd until all instances of the class containing `i` are gone.

Comment: @DaDaDom `i` will survive any instances of the class. In fact, it has absolutely nothing to do with the instances of the class.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik hm, I always thought that `private` static variable is only created on the first appearance of an instance of the class. But it seems I am wrong ...

Comment: @DaDaDom So what do I use to get it to create *only once*??

Comment: @DaDaDom The *class is initialized* upon first access of that class, which does not need to be an instance creation expression.

Comment: @user2763361 You already create it only once. Do you have an actual problem?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik If I use a loop and keep going `i = 500` in each loop iteration, will this `i` have the same stack address or will it keep going on and off the heap?

Comment: `Integer` is immutable. Each distinct value must be represented by a distinct instance of `Integer`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Okay so if I set `i=1`, the original `i` (which was valued at `0`) will need to be GCd eventually and `i=1` will be a new instance of `Integer` ? Also, if I set `i=0` will a new instance of `Integer` be created?

Comment: Every time you write `new Integer()`, a new instance is guaranteed to be created.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I'm not writing `new Integer()`, I am asking just about `i=5` whereas previous to this `i.equals(0)` returned `true`.

Comment: OK, so you're really asking about `Integer.valueOf(5)`---this factory method caches all `Integer` between -128 and 127. Outside of that region, it's the same as `new Integer()`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Alright so if I go `i=5` *after* setting `i=0`, then no GC is needed?

Comment: No. But you asked about `i = 500` half an hour ago, so your actual question has become a moving target.

Answer (score 1):

Java primitive types (int, long, float, etc) but not their object counterparts (Integer, Long, Float, etc) are passed by value. Additionally references to objects are passed by value. The objects themselves though are passed by reference.

So if you call a method x() with an object O then:

```
O o = new O(); // Create an O on the heap, put a reference to it on the stack

x(o); // Pass a copy of the reference into x, the reference still points to O
```

Inside X:

```
void x(O o) {
    // o is a separate reference, so if you do o = null; it does not chance the reference in the calling function.
    // but the o itself is shared, so if you do o->doSomething() the calling function will be able to see the results of doSomething().
}
```

In your example when you call `pushThroughMethod(i)` then a new reference to `i` is created, but it is pointing to the same `Integer`.

`i` will only be eligible for Garbage Collection once all Strong References to it have gone. In this case even when pushThroughMethod() drops it's reference to `i` the static reference will remain and prevent collection.

Comment: "... references to objects are passed by value.
All objects on the other hand are passed by reference." There you say the same thing twice, but use "on the other hand", as if they were opposites.

Comment: They are counterparts. In one hand you have references passed by value, in the other hand you have objects passed by reference.

Comment: "Mothers bear children. On the other hand, each child was born by a mother"---does that make sense? As much as your words.

Comment: I guess we have a dialect difference in quite what the saying means. I will edit it since it's potentially confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a variable of the reference type `java.lang.Integer`. Whatever you assign to it is a reference to an *object* of that type.

Clearly, you have an object on the heap to begin with, regardless of any method calls.

If, instead, you had an `int` variable, and you passed it to a method that takes an `Integer` argument, then you would be right in saying that an `Integer` instance will get involved just due to that method call.

Whether that call made a *new* instance of `Integer` is an internal detail of the JVM, and subject to at least the following concerns (valid for HotSpot 7):

- if the value is within the range [-128,127], then a cached `Integer` instance will be used;
- for other values a new instance *may* be created on the heap, but may also be stack-allocated. If the latter, there may not even be a full object on the stack, but just the `int` value. All this is subject to the depth of optimization performed by the JIT compiler.

Lastly, note that [in a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807388/why-is-the-new-keyword-so-much-more-efficient-than-assignment/20807788#20807788), it was measured that `new Integer(1)` actually produced *faster* code than `Integer.valueOf(1)` (the question is about `Character`, but otherwise the story is exactly the same).